# Getting JavaScript Error: "e is null" when using assert to verify javascript alert text

Tags: java, javascript, selenium

In my program, I get the following javascript alert
[image]

I am able to switch to this alert. I am able to get the text and click the OK and Cancel buttons. The issue I am having is when using assertequals to verify the alert text. I am using the below code

```
String Test = driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
System.out.println(Test);
Assert.assertEquals(Test, "You are sharing your report with \"Limited Overall-10000 \".\n\nThis will share your report with \"179\" people. Continue?");
```

System.out.println correctly prints the text of the alert box. However, I get the below error when trying to use assertequals. Its strange because these same steps work for other javascript alerts on the page.

```
 org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: [JavaScript Error: "e is null" {file: "file:///C:/Users/IBM_AD~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous2086351268768311654webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js" line: 7716}]
```

Comment: Are you actually calling `assertEquals(test,...)` or are you really calling `assertEquals(driver.switchTo().alert().getText(),...)`?

Comment: I am calling assertEquals(test,...)

Comment: So if you comment out the `Assert.assertEquals(...)` line, you don't get an error?

Comment: @ColinDeClue - Correct. I do not get an error if I comment that line out.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error.

Turns out I was closing the webdriver *before* I had dismissed the alert box.

Closing/clicking the alert *and then* closing the driver fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You've run into a bug in Selenium:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7977

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3544

(Yes, the two bug reports are related.)

There's a problem in Selenium whereby if you try to terminate the driver while an alert is active, you'll get `e is null` or a number of other error messages. As Lawrence Tierney mentioned, you should make sure that the alert is closed before terminating the driver. Your code should do this *whether or not the assert is successful*.