# For Python, getting WebDriverException: Message: u'[JavaScript Error: "e is null"

Tags: javascript, python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've come across a scenario that seems to only fail on Firefox under certain conditions.  In my code...

```
    driver.get(url('/Points/Inputs/'))
    assertRowTrue(driver, 2, 11, "True")
```

I'm receiving the error...

```
E           WebDriverException: Message: u'[JavaScript Error: "e is null" {file:
 "file:///tmp/anonymous7279155570809486473webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@
googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js" line: 7854}]\'[JavaScript Error:
 "e is null" {file: "file:///tmp/anonymous7279155570809486473webdriver-profile/e
xtensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js" line: 7854}]\
' when calling method: [nsICommandProcessor::execute]\nBuild info: version: \'2.
43.0\', revision: \'597b76b\', time: \'2014-09-09 20:52:14\'\nSystem info: host:
 \'8efca6f08729\', ip: \'172.17.0.3\', os.name: \'Linux\', os.arch: \'amd64\', o
s.version: \'3.13.0-24-generic\', java.version: \'1.7.0_65\'\nDriver info: drive
r.version: unknown' ; Screenshot: available via screen
```

Looking around, this issue was mention and explained in a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212405/getting-javascript-error-e-is-null-when-using-assert-to-verify-javascript-ale?answertab=active#tab-top).  The problem with my particular scenario is that it's NOT the result of an Alert, so when I attempt close the alert...

```
driver.switch_to_alert().dismiss()
```

...I receive a `NoAlertPresentException`.

Is there a way to get around this error when an Alert is not the culprit until Selenium gets around to fixing this issue?

### UPDATE (June 6, 2015)

Trying the answer listed below worked for a while, but went back to the original error I was seeing.  Here's an example of a test I have that's failing.

Hey @alecxc.  Here's an example that fails.  I visit a specific web page to verify that a row [in a table] contains the information that I expected it to.  For this, I used my own definition **assertRowTrue()**

`assertRowTrue(driver, 2, 11, "Online")`

The this def, I've created the code.

```
def assertRowTrue(driver, row, column, value):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "//tr["+str(row)+"]/td["+str(column)+"]/div"), value)
        )
    except TimeoutException:
        raise Exception("ERROR : VALUE NOT EQUAL TO EXPECTED VALUE \""+value+"\".  ACTUAL VALUE:  ", driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr["+str(row)+"]/td["+str(column)+"]/div").text)
```

..where **row** and **column** point to the location in the table & **value** represents the value to expect there. On Firefox, it fails at the **expected_condition()** portion of the code.  Chrome, however, runs this code without any errors.

Comment: Which firefox version are you using?

Comment: Mozilla Firefox 36.0

Comment: I once ran into an issue where the error was caused by an alert that came up just as `quit()` was executing. I would not actually *see* the alert because everything was happening too fast. I added code to close the alert but then I found that sometimes this code would execute too fast: the alert was created asynchronously but `dismiss()` would sometimes execute before the alert existed. A quick way to *check* whether maybe you're running into a race condition would be to add `time.sleep(<a few seconds>)` just before `driver.switch_to_alert().dismiss()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are experiencing **compatibility issues** between `selenium` 2.43 and `firefox` 36.

The easiest option right now would be to **upgrade selenium** to 2.45:

```
pip install --upgrade selenium
```

Comment: I upgraded selenium to 2.45 successfully, but when I run my test scenario, it still fails with the same error message.

Comment: @rwbyrd just a quick check before I'll delete the answer: try downgrading firefox to 34.0.5.

Comment: Sorry, putting out a lot of fires right now.  Will try this tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: Hey @alecxe.  I just finished giving this a try & that resolved the issue.  The combination of upgrading selenium & downgrading Firefox to 34.0.5 made the tests in question run successfully.  Did I mention you were awesome!?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hey @alecxe, I had this issue come back again this morning.  I tried using 36 & then downgraded back to 34.0.5 and the issue continues.  The one change that has happened before this started occurring again was Windows 7 had some downloads that were install in the past few days.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @rwbyrd in case of firefox 34.0.5, make sure you are using selenium 2.44 or above.

Comment: using selenium 2.45 on Python 2.7

Comment: do you have anymore thoughts on this??  I appreciate your help up to this point.  @alecxe

Comment: @rwbyrd what's the current state of the problem? What firefox and selenium versions are you currently using?

Comment: @alecxc Here's what I'm currently using: firefox 34.0.5, py==1.4.22, pytest==2.6.0, requests==2.3.0, robotframework==2.8.5, robotframework-selenium2library==1.5.0, selenium==2.45.0

Comment: @rwbyrd not yet, need more information. What is your current code and what errors are you getting? Thanks.

Comment: Hey @alecxc.  I added some sample code in the description above.  Let me know if you need more examples or anything else details-wise.

Comment: @rwbyrd what if you try with firefox 35.0.1 and selenium 2.45? Thanks.

Comment: Hey @alecxc.  Just got back from vacation.  As soon as I finish putting out a few bonfires, so-to-speak, I'll give this a try.  Thanks!

Comment: @alecxc  I updated Firefox to 35.0.1.  Selenium was already at 2.45.  I gave that a try and received the same error.  I tried updating Selenium to 2.46.0 to see if that would make a difference, but the behavior remained the same.